# Datetimepicker from now but next day from x time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

When user select a time it shows past time, say right know is 10am it should not show any time below 10am(right now), BUT, if user selects next day or any other following day the start time should be at 8am until 8pm, here is the process.
User selects a date with this format: 2019-01-17, now based on that date we show ajax information and based on that information the user now can select a time.

Here is where the whole enchilada starts... this time has to be based on current time when the selected date is current, the time has to show only from current time plus an hour, say now is 10am then your options for time will be 11, 12, 13, 14... etc
But if you select any other day from current day then your options for time will be from 9am til 8pm...

currently I only have this:

```
$(_TimeSelector).datetimepicker({
    lang      : 'en',
    datepicker: false,
    format    : 'H:s',
    allowTimes:[
    '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00'
    ],
    minDate:0
});
```

and there is the problem I don't know how to build the array for the `allowTimes` based on the selected date...
any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
    
   var times = [ '09:00','10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00'];
   
 jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y/m/d H:i',  
  allowTimes:times,
  
   onSelectDate:function(dp){
        var date = new Date().dateFormat('Y/m/d');
   if( dp.dateFormat('Y/m/d')==date ){
    var timeNow =dp.dateFormat('H:i');
      var new_times = times.filter(function(x) {
      return x > timeNow ;
    });
         this.setOptions({
         allowTimes:new_times
          });
         }
       else{
        this.setOptions({
         allowTimes:times
        });
    }

  }
 });
```

```css
.dt{
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="dt" type="text" id="datetimepicker"/>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
 <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```